# Unable to trigger a page change in a nested route of a Remix.run web app

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

I have a nested route in a remix.run web application. The route is located at `app/routes/games/$gameId/pick-song.tsx`. When I invoke the `action` function for the route, the `redirect` does not cause the page to change and I remain on the same page.

Here is the function:

```
export async function action({ request, params }: ActionArgs) {
  await selectSong({ userId, gameId: params.gameId, songChoiceId: song.id });

  return redirect(`/games/${params.gameId}`); // I define a route at `app/routes/games/$gameId/index.tsx` that loads when I enter the url in the browser.
}
```

This is what appears in the console:

```
POST /games/e5cc3156-c85d-4d33-affe-a325fde27565/pick-song?_data=routes%2Fgames%2F%24gameId%2Fpick-song 204 - - 38.933 ms
GET /games/e5cc3156-c85d-4d33-affe-a325fde27565?_data=routes%2Fgames%2F%24gameId%2Findex 200 - - 43.864 ms
GET /games/e5cc3156-c85d-4d33-affe-a325fde27565/pick-song 200 - - 34.207 ms
```

I also added a `<Link to={`/games/${gameId}`}>Go to game detail page</Link>` to the page and when I click on that, it does not trigger a page change either. The following appears in the console:

```
GET /games/95a71e55-11ae-427c-a6d3-8dc7bd5f2d8f?_data=routes%2Fgames%2F%24gameId%2Findex 200 - - 63.471 ms
GET /games/95a71e55-11ae-427c-a6d3-8dc7bd5f2d8f/pick-song 200 - - 39.986 ms
```

What I find particularly strange is that for both `redirect` and `<Link />`, the `loader` function of the route I want to switch to is invoked but the component function which I put as the default export per the Remix convention is not.

I tried to trigger a page change in a Remix.run web application from one nested route to another using both `redirect()` in the action function and a  component. In both cases, I was expecting the page to change but instead the page remains the same. However, the loader function of the page I want to switch to is invoked and in the console there is a mention of a page switch with a `_data` query param followed by the url of the page that I am navigating from.

Comment: If you go directly to `/games/:gameId`, do you see your route? Is the issue only happening during client navigation? If you can create a sample repo, it would be easier to help.